# Resize form by only specific sizes

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, window-resize

I want to allow any form height, but only specific widths (300, 550 , 800, ...(+250)). I tried this code:

```
Resize += (s, a) => {
    if (Width < 425)
        Width = 300;
    else if (Width < 675)
        Width = 550;
    else if (Width < 925)
        Width = 800;
    else ... 
};
```

When I try to resize my form, border fluctuates between mouse position and expected width. How can I achieve that behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sizing or BeforeResize event for Form

To control size of the form, ResizeEnd or SizeChanged are a bit late and if you want to change the size in those events, it results in flickering.

To handle sizing before the new size applies, you can hanlde [WM-SIZING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-sizing?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) message which includes the proposed size and the edge of the form which has triggered the resize.

In the following example, I've set a tile size for the form and tried to resize based on the tiles:

[image]

```
private int widthGridSize = 200;
private int heightGridSize = 1;

private const int WM_SIZING = 0x0214;
enum EdgeType : int
{
    WMSZ_LEFT = 1,
    WMSZ_RIGHT = 2,
    WMSZ_TOP = 3,
    WMSZ_TOPLEFT = 4,
    WMSZ_TOPRIGHT = 5,
    WMSZ_BOTTOM = 6,
    WMSZ_BOTTOMLEFT = 7,
    WMSZ_BOTTOMRIGHT = 8
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class RECT
{
    public int L, T, R, B;
    public int W => R - L;
    public int H => B - T;
}
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_SIZING)
    {
        var flag = (EdgeType)m.WParam;
        var rect = new RECT();
        Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, rect);
        var w = (int)Math.Round((double)rect.W / widthGridSize) * widthGridSize;
        var h = (int)Math.Round((double)rect.H / heightGridSize) * heightGridSize;
        switch (flag)
        {
            case EdgeType.WMSZ_LEFT:
                rect.L = rect.R - w;
                break;
            case EdgeType.WMSZ_RIGHT:
                rect.R = rect.L + w;
                break;
            case EdgeType.WMSZ_TOP:
                rect.T = rect.B - h;
                break;
            case EdgeType.WMSZ_TOPLEFT:
                rect.T = rect.B - h;
                rect.L = rect.R - w;
                break;
            case EdgeType.WMSZ_TOPRIGHT:
                rect.T = rect.B - h;
                rect.R = rect.L + w;
                break;
            case EdgeType.WMSZ_BOTTOM:
                rect.B = rect.T + h;
                break;
            case EdgeType.WMSZ_BOTTOMLEFT:
                rect.B = rect.T + h;
                rect.L = rect.R - w;
                break;
            case EdgeType.WMSZ_BOTTOMRIGHT:
                rect.B = rect.T + h;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(rect, m.LParam, true);
        m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
    }
    else
        base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that you're doing this in the `Resize` event, so as soon as the mouse starts to move, the event fires, and your code resizes the form.

Instead, try using the `ResizeEnd` event, which only fires after the user stops resizing:

```
ResizeEnd += (s, a) =>
{
    var widths = new[] {300, 550, 800, 1050, 1300, 1550, 1800};
    Width = widths.First(w => Width < w + 125);
};
```

Comment: There we go. It's been awhile since I've worked in Winforms

Comment: Almost a solution. It would be better if the form sharply resized from 300px to 550px, from 1 column of data to 2 columns of fixed size

Comment: I thought that's what your code already did, but you didn't want it to fluctuate? Please clarify the question. What isn't working with your code, and what behavior do you want to see instead?

Comment: "I thought that's what your code already did, but you didn't want it to fluctuate?". Yes, it is.